# Call and run model/equation when in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, equation

Based on the data frame presented below, I would like to run the formulas in column 'struct'. Basically, I'd need an R function that treats the equations in column 'struct' as code. Any ideas very welcome!

```
x <- runif(60, min = 2, max = 35)
y <- runif(60, min = 0, max = 10)
z <- runif(60, min = 5, max = 20)
struct1 <- rep("x + y + z", times = 20)
struct2 <- rep("x - y - z", times = 20)
struct3 <- rep("x * y * z", times = 20)
struct <- c(struct1, struct2, struct3)
dd <- data.frame(x, y, z, struct)
rm(x, y, z, struct, struct1, struct2, struct3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not very elegant but works:

```
set.seed(1)
library(data.table)
x <- runif(60, min = 2, max = 35)
y <- runif(60, min = 0, max = 10)
z <- runif(60, min = 5, max = 20)
struct1 <- rep("x + y + z", times = 20)
struct2 <- rep("x - y - z", times = 20)
struct3 <- rep("x * y * z", times = 20)

struct <- c(struct1, struct2, struct3)
struct_1<-paste("function(x,y,z){",struct,"}",sep="")
struct_2<-paste(paste("func_",seq(1:length(struct)),"<-",sep=""),sep="")
struct<-paste(struct_2,struct_1,sep="")
struct<-paste(struct,
              paste(gsub("<-","",struct_2),"(x,y,z)",sep=""),sep="\n ")
dd <- data.frame(x, y, z, struct)
rm(x, y, z, struct, struct1, struct2, struct3)
dd<-as.data.table(dd)
dd[,needed_var:=eval(parse(text=as.character(struct))),by=1:nrow(dd)]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. However, the code doesn't seem to work for me, could you maybe look if there's a bug?

Comment: It is strange, I just reran it in a new session and it works (did you load data.table library?

Comment: Yes, I didn't notice I didn't have data.table installed! It works, many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This one line of code will evaluate the corresponding formula in struct and store the results in `dd$result`.

```
x <- runif(60, min = 2, max = 35)
y <- runif(60, min = 0, max = 10)
z <- runif(60, min = 5, max = 20)
struct1 <- rep("x + y + z", times = 20)
struct2 <- rep("x - y - z", times = 20)
struct3 <- rep("x * y * z", times = 20)
struct <- c(struct1, struct2, struct3)
dd <- data.frame(x, y, z, struct, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
rm(x, y, z, struct, struct1, struct2, struct3)

dd$result <- sapply(1:nrow(dd), function(i) with(dd[i,], eval(parse(text = struct))))
```